# How to hide a GridViewColumn as if it's collapsed at runtime in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, gridviewcolumn

Basically I have some `CheckBox` controls I want to use to show or hide certain `GridViewColumns` at runtime. But I failed to find a sort of `IsVisible` property that I can set to false. Or even a `Visibility` property that exist only on `GridViewColumnHeader`.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the GridViewColumn Width property to 0. This will achieve the same effect as hiding it. This can be achieved with DataBinding and a Converter.

Comment: Thanks, I did it but the cells aren't hidden after doing this. I want the whole column to be gone as if I resized the column to nothing by hand at runtime.

Comment: This works in the designer. Just set the width of a column to 0 and you'll see it disappear. If it isn't working, then there is an issue in your implementation.

Comment: Thanks it works, I got tripped by a WPF gimmick I asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574613/why-are-there-separate-events-for-the-checked-and-unchecked-state-for-a-wpf-check